# Resultant particle distribution function for mixing of two particle species

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, turbulence, solar-wind

I would like to know if there is any way to compute the resultant particle distribution for system where two kinds of particles are mixed. For me one kind is Maxwellian and another is non-thermal kappa distribution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless something else is going on, once the two come into thermal equilibrium, the overall distribution has to be the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution. I don't believe initial conditions affect anything.

Comment: @ZachJohnson - Plasmas are not in thermal equilibrium unless they are collisionally mediated.  Most lab plasmas have sufficient collisions to help maintain some semblance of thermal distributions.  In a weakly collisional plasma like the solar wind, the end result of Coulomb collisions is NOT a Maxwellian (e.g., see https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/ac222b and references therein).

Comment: @honeste_vivere - Yes, good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a weakly collisional [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) like the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind), each particle species (e.g., electrons) has multiple populations [e.g., see [Wilson et al., 2019](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4365/ab22bd)].  They can do this because the [Coulomb collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision) rate is on the order of one per day [e.g., see [Wilson et al., 2018](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4365/aab71c)].  Even so, the end state of Coulomb collisions in a weakly collisional plasma is not a Maxwellian [e.g., see [Randol, 2021](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/ac222b)]

> I would like to know if there is any way to compute the resultant particle distribution for system where two kinds of particles are mixed. For me one kind is Maxwellian and another is non-thermal kappa distribution.

The velocity distributions are additive in this case, as discussed in [Wilson et al. [2019]](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-4365/ab22bd).